# How can marginalizing over intermediate variable give arbitrarily complex distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

In this [web page](http://ruishu.io/2017/01/14/one-bit/) has the following statement regarding an inference model
$$
   q(z_2,z_1|x) = q(z_2|z_1) q(z_1|x) 
$$

> "Although we are still sticking to Gaussians for all of the factorized distributions, it is worth noting that $q(z_2 | x)$ is potentially an arbitrarily complex distribution since we get to marginalize over the latent variable $z_1$."

Can anyone explain this statement?  The part about why it can be arbitrarily complex?

Actually I do not see the marginalization in the blog post, but I ssume it is meaning
$$
   q(z_2|x) = \int q(z_2|z_1) q(z_1|x) d z_1
$$